# How does $e^{-\alpha t}\left[K_ae^{j\omega_dt}+K_be^{-j\omega_dt}\right]$ become $Ke^{-\alpha t}\cos(\omega_dt+\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand the following simplification:

[image]

When I expand the element between brackets above, I get:

$(K_a + K_b)cos(\omega_dt) + j(K_a - K_b)sin(\omega_dt)$

How can the $sin$ disappear and the $\theta$ appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take it from the top. You have a derivation of a homogeneous solution to a differential equation:

$$v_h(t) = e^{-\alpha t} \left[ K_a e^{j \omega_d t} + K_b e^{-j \omega_d t} \right]$$

Applying Euler's formula $e^{jx} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x)$ and $e^{-jx} = \cos(x) - j\sin(x)$ to each of the complex exponentials we get:

$$K_a e^{j \omega_d t} = K_a(\cos(\omega_d t) + j\sin(\omega_d t))$$
$$K_b e^{-j \omega_d t} = K_b(\cos(\omega_d t) - j\sin(\omega_d t))$$

Now, you've added these two parts together and that's how you got to the result you mentioned in your question. Let us first assume that $K_a$ and $K_b$ are complex conjugates of each other, which is typically the case in these solutions (and the end result shown in the image confirms it is the case here) as it ensures the resulting expression is real, not complex. $K_a$ and $K_b$ being complex conjugates means their imaginary parts are equal in magnitude but opposed in sign.

Let x be a complex number $x = a + bj$ where j is the imaginary number. The complex conjugate of x would be denoted as $\overline{x} = a - bj$.

If $K_a$ and $K_b$ are complex conjugates, considering the results we got after applying Euler's formula:

$$K_a e^{j \omega_d t} = K_a(\cos(\omega_d t) + j\sin(\omega_d t))$$
$$K_b e^{-j \omega_d t} = K_b(\cos(\omega_d t) - j\sin(\omega_d t))$$

If $K_a = a + bj$ and $K_b = a - bj$:

$$(a + bj)((\cos(\omega_d t) + j\sin(\omega_d t))$$
$$(a - bj)((\cos(\omega_d t) - j\sin(\omega_d t))$$

Therefore, $K_a + K_b$ can be written as:

$$a\cos(\omega_d t) + aj\sin(\omega_d t) + bj\cos(\omega_d t) - b\sin(\omega_d t)) + a\cos(\omega_d t) - aj\sin(\omega_d t) -bj\cos(\omega_d t) - b\sin(\omega_d t)$$

Considering that $aj\sin(\omega_d t)$ cancels out $-aj\sin(\omega_d t)$, $bj\cos(\omega_d t)$ cancels out $-bj\cos(\omega_d t)$, we're left with:

$$2a\cos(\omega_d t) - 2b\sin(\omega_d t)$$.

which is a linear combination of the sine and cosine functions. We can apply the trigonometric identify:

$$A\cos(x) + B\sin(x) = K(\cos(x) - \theta)$$

Where $K = \sqrt(A^2 + B^2)$ and $theta = arctan(B/A)$

Applying the identity to $2a\cos(\omega_d t) - 2b\sin(\omega_d t)$ gives:

$$2\sqrt(a^2 + bˆ2)\cos(\omega_d t - \arctan(-b/a))$$

Given that $K = sqrt(a^2 + bˆ2)$ is the amplitude of the damped oscillation and $\theta = arctan(-b/a)$ is the phase shift, adding in the exponential damping term yields:

$$v_h(t) = e^{-\alpha t} K \cos(\omega_d t + \theta)$$

The phase $\theta$ is determined by the relationship between $K_a$ and $K_b$. If there is no phase difference, $\theta$ is zero. Depending on the values of a and b and how they relate in the arctan, theta will be positive or negative.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate the part in which the complex conjugates Ka and Kb cancel out the sin? What is multiplying the sin is (Ka - Kb); if they are complex conjugates, the real part should disappear and the imaginary one should be multiplied by 2, am I wrong?

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to include it in the comment and added an edit to my answer. Please let me know if you have any follow up questions. Hope it helps!

Comment: I agree with everything except from the last term. How does $-bj(-j)sin(w_dt)$ produce $bsin(w_dt)$? $j(-j) = 1$, so $-b \times 1 \times sin(w_dt)$ is $-bsin(w_dt)$, right?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I made a mistake there with the sign. I re-did the calculation with the correct sign (edited the answer) so it should be correct now. Let me know if you have any other questions.